# Sharepoint 2010 silverlight web part not available

Tags: silverlight-4.0, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have developed a silverlight application with WCF-RIA services and is working fine. I have to deploy this application on a Sharepoint 2010 site.

I am new to Sharepoint 2010. I am having "Full Control" on the site. But when I am in edit mode, not able to see "Media and Content" category which is having "Silverlight" web part.

New web page -> edit page -> Insert -> Web part.

This may be a simple setting issue. Can someone please help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've to activate the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" Site Collection Feature. After activating all the Silverlight WebParts are available.

Thorsten

Comment: Thanks Thorsten. Along with that, I had to make another setting. Providing access to the web parts which was preventing users from viewing all the web parts.

Answer (score 1):

Along with whatever Thorsten has mentioned, I had to make another setting. Providing access to the web parts which was preventing users from viewing all the web parts